# Exception removing expired grants: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using Identity Server 4.1.1 on Docker Kubernetes. I have an environment with 2 k8s clusters with 10 pods each running Identity Server. I am getting this error only on this environment and not in any other with lesser number of pods.

```
<PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="4.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.EntityFramework" Version="4.1.1" />
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddOperationalStore(options =>
                        {
                            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                                builder.UseSqlServer(operationalStoreConnectionString, sql => sql.EnableRetryOnFailure());

                            options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                            options.TokenCleanupInterval = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalSeconds);
                        })
```

I have thousands of records in my PersistedGrants table but no expired grants.

Exception:

> Exception removing expired grants: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Thanks. Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis, we figured out that the issue was not with Identity Server but the way we had setup network infrastructure on our Azure AKS VM. We ran into a problem called SNAT port exhaustion which simply means we had run out of ports.

You can find more details [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/reaching-azure-sql-db-connection-limits-in-many-ways/ba-p/1369218)